# Django Testing - ImportError: Start directory is not importable

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I was trying to do a bit of testing on a pieace of code but I get the ImportError: Start directory is not importable. Below is my code. I would really appreciate if someone could help. I am using Python 2.7.5 and also pycharm.

This is the command I execute in virenv

> manage.py test /project/tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase

# Create your tests here.
from project.models import Projects
from signup.models import SignUp


class ProjectTestCase(TestCase):

    def SetUp(self):
        super(ProjectTestCase,self).SetUp()
        self.john = SignUp.objects.get(email='john@john.com')
        self.project = Projects.objects.get(pk=1)


    def test_project_permission(self):


        self.assertFalse(self.john.has_perm('delete',self.project))
        self.assertTrue(self.john.has_perm('view',self.project))
        self.assertTrue(self.john.has_perm('change',self.project))
```

Comment: Dont use absolute paths. You can just do `./manage.py test project`

Comment: please see my response under the Foon's answer.

Comment: It is `setUp()` not `SetUp()`

Comment: still gives me the table already exists error as I described under Foon's response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should verify that you have an `__init__.py` in your project directory (it can be an empty file)
2. You're not calling test correctly.  Assuming you have an app known as project, the way to call the tests in that app is manage.py test project

[Edit for additional comment which is really getting into separate question territory]

I would suggest adding this to settings.py (at the bottom)

```
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}
    SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

This:

A. Will use sqlite (sort of, I'm not sure if it's actually sqlite or an in-memory db that works like sqlite) ... I've noticed issues if I use postgres and am trying to have my permissions not be excessively liberal AND I've had a test abort)

B.  Disables south migrations (so it will just start with a clean database built against whatever models are currently saying)

Comment: my __init__.py is an empty file. Now I did what ./manage.py test project(@karthikr: it works with both absolute and relative path) now I am getting an error on creating test database that one of the tables already exists! I am using south.

Comment: If my suggestion doesn't work, I'd suggest pasting the error message you're now getting

Comment: @Foon: Thank you. That is it! `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` I did not have to include `DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}` since it appears that the test engine uses the in memory database.